# convert Ruby array of class into JSON

Tags: ruby, json

I have a Ruby data structure as such:

```
class Albums
    attr_accessor :title, :url

    def initialize(title, url)
        @title = title
        @url = url
    end
end

class Albumlist < Albums
    attr_accessor :id, :albums

    def initialize(id)
        @id = id
        @albums = Array.new
    end
end
```

And I made an array of *Albumlist* which looks like (using .inspect method):

```
[#<Albumlist:0x8db6390 @id="abc",@albums=[
     #<Albums:0x8db6098 @title="123", @url="test">,
     #<Albums:0x8db5fe4 @title="456", @url="test">
 ]>,
 #<Albumlist:0x8f4042c @id="def", @albums=[
     #<Albums:0x8f49f2c @title="Untitled Album", @url="test">
 ]>
]
```

I am not sure if this array looks okay but once I used the method .to_json or JSON.generate() on this array, all I get is:

```
["#<Albumlist:0x8db6390>","#<Albumlist:0x8f4042c>"]
```

It looks like Ruby returns the "reference" to the object instances.
I want to convert this array in JSON which should look like

```
[
    {
            "id":"abc"
            "albums":[
                    {
                            "title":"123",
                            "url":"test"
                    },
                    {
                            "title":"456",
                            "url":"test"
                    }
            ]
    },
    {
            "id":"def"
            "albums":[
                    {
                            "title":"Untitled Album",
                            "url":"test"
                    }
            ]
    }
]
```

and I believe I am missing something, such as converting the array into some kind of intermediate object?

**EDIT: Alternate Solution**

Define a to_json method in class Albumlist as such:

```
def to_json(*a)
    {
        "id" => @id,
        "albums" => @albums
    }.to_json(*a)
end
```

And use it instead..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it works, probably you are not applying the method on the right moment, let's try it, first, focusing on the array with something like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_support/all'
class Albums
    attr_accessor :title, :url

    def initialize(title, url)
        @title = title
        @url = url
    end
end

class Albumlist < Albums
    attr_accessor :id, :albums

    def initialize(id)
        @id = id
        @albums = Array.new
    end
end

a = Albums.new("a", "www.a.com")
b = Albums.new("b", "www.b.com")
c = Albums.new("c", "www.c.com")

list_of_albums_list = Array.new
list_a = Albumlist.new(1)
list_b = Albumlist.new(2)

list_a.albums << a
list_a.albums << b
list_b.albums << c

list_of_albums_list << list_a
list_of_albums_list << list_b
puts list_of_albums_list.to_json
```

And the output is:

```
[{"albums":[{"title":"a","url":"www.a.com"},{"title":"b","url":"www.b.com"}],"id":1},{"albums":[{"title":"c","url":"www.c.com"}],"id":2}]
```

therefore the method works as expected.

Comment: Copied and pasted your code. Doesn't work. What command did you use to get that output?

Comment: @SunnyJ. Really straightforward for me here, ruby albums.rb, considering albums.rb with the source I mentioned. ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [x86_64-linux], and Rails 2.3.5.

Comment: My guess is that he and I are both using 1.9 or higher.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I've found the culprit. Your code "requires" 'active_support/all', but I ignored it and used 'json' instead.  No error occured but the outcome is incorrect.  Using 'active_support/all' fixed the problem.  I am guessing that's because 1.9.3 includes a better version of json implementation than the json gem (perhaps?).  Anyways thanks for the answer.