# Enumerable changes my `to_json` behavior

Tags: ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-1.9.3, enumerable

I have a rails application and a class I've wrote as a part of it (not an ActiveRecord or anything..). The data is stored in simple instance variables (string, integers, arrays...)

When I invoke `to_json` on an instance of it I get what I expect to. A JSON object, containing all instance variables as JSON objects too.

However, when I add `include Enumerable` to the class definition, the behavior of `to_json` changes and I get an empty object: `"[]"`

Any idea why is that? Does `Enumerable` somehow defined or undefines something that affects `to_json`?

Thanks!

Comment: Check this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292739/convert-ruby-array-of-class-into-json][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292739/convert-ruby-array-of-class-into-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what happens is:

Rails loads in ActiveSupport. ActiveSupport injects (monkey patches) these `as_json` methods into several classes and modules, including `Enumerable`:

```
module Enumerable
  def as_json(options = nil) #:nodoc:
    to_a.as_json(options)
  end
end
```

You're probably returning nothing for the `each` method Enumerable requires you to have, so `to_a` returns `[]`, and an empty array gets converted into the String `"[]"`.

What you can do here, is, to bind your object into a non-enumerable inherited class, and use its `.as_json` method.

Like this:

```
class A
  def as_json(*)
    Object.instance_method(:as_json).bind(self).call
  end  
end
```

Demo:

```
➜ pry
require 'active_support/all'
=> true

class A
  def initialize
    @a = 1
  end  
end  
=> nil

A.new.to_json
=> "{\"a\":1}"

class A
  include Enumerable
  def each
  end
end
=> nil

A.new.to_json
=> "[]"

class A
  def as_json(*)
    Object.instance_method(:as_json).bind(self).call
  end  
end  
=> nil

A.new.to_json
=> "{\"a\":1}"
```